# Coger solo un array de objeto de la clase al recibir tres arrays en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un constructor que me define 3 variables como arrays en la **clase displayQuerys**. Una función de esta clase me rellena el array ***"activities"*** para posteriormente, en un html imprimirme este array.

El problema con el que me he encontrado, es que al crear un nuevo objeto, me devuelve los tres arrays, cuando yo solo quiero uno de ellos.

```
     displayQuerys Object
(
    [schedule:displayQuerys:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [activities:displayQuerys:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [instructors:displayQuerys:private] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

El foreach deja de funcionar porque necesito solo uno de los arrays.

```
<?php
  $activity = new displayQuerys();
  $activity->showActivities(); // Rellena el array de Activities

  print_r($activity); // works fine

  foreach ($activity as $value) {  // here stops working
    echo "I'm supossed to do stuff";
  }
?>
```

¿Hay alguna manera de al crear dicho objeto, especificar cual escoger <strike>o almenos aislar para que en este caso pueda coger ***"activities"*** y en otra ocasión, escoger ***instructores***</strike>?

**Edit: Mi problema ha sido solucionado añadiendo un return en el método de la clase displayQueries, de esta manera si puedo aplicar la solución de Carlos:**

```
if ($result->num_rows>0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $this->activities[]=$row;
     }
     return $this->activities;
   } else {
       echo "0 results";
     }
     $conn->close();
   }
```

Comment: y si intentas asignar una variable de esta manera `$a = $activity->showActivities();` y luego recorres es dicha variable con el foreach?

Comment: ¿Puedes definir nuevos métodos en la clase displayQuerys? Nota adicional, el plural de Query es Queries.

Comment: En respuesta a Carlos, lo he probado pero me devuelve un valor NULL.
@Muriano si te refieres a crear métodos nuevos y usarlos si, tengo otros dos pero son muy similares al resto, ya que usan los otros dos arrays, Activities y Instructors por lo que me contraré con el mismo problema del que no soy capaz de aislar estos arrays.